# How do I create an ArrayList of objects from another class in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to create an ArrayList of instances from another class in my program. In my case the class I am trying to create an ArrayList of is called record with the parameters firstname, lastname, and email. I have created another class called emailList and I am trying to instantiate the array list there. I am getting the error "The non-generic type 'ArrayList' cannot be used with type arguments".

Here is the code I have to create record objects in the Record class:

```
public class Record
    {
        private String firstname;
        private String lastname;
        private String email;
        public Record(String firstNameIn, String lastNameIn, String emailIn)
        {
            firstname = firstNameIn;
            lastname = lastNameIn;
            email = emailIn;
        }
```

In the emailList class I am trying to create an ArrayList in the emailList class using:

`ArrayList<Record> eList = new ArrayList<Record>;`

Comment: Was there a problem with your attempt to create an ArrayList?  If so, what was it?

Comment: ArrayList is a very old class. It's available since .NET framework 1.x where we didn't have generics yet.

Comment: Im sorry I am pretty new to coding so bear with me here, but i want the list to contain records in an array not just a regular list. Is there not a difference in the format of the two?

Comment: There is not generic `ArrayList` in .NET, so instead of `ArrayList<Record>` you probably want `List<Record>`. Stay away from the old `ArrayList`.

Comment: @RyanCarney if you want to use an array, you can do with with `var myArray = new Record[3]; myArray[0] = new Record("first", "last", "e-mail");` `List<T>` uses an array to store items which is expanded when the list reaches its capacity, e.g.: `var myList = new List<Record>(); myList.Add(new Record("first", "last", "e-mail"));`

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList` is not generic meaning you cannot provide an generic argument (e.g.: `ArrayList<Record>`), you need to instantiate it as `var eList = new ArrayList();`

For type-safe collection check `List<T>` under `System.Collections.Generic` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a type specifier for `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList eList = new ArrayList();
eList.Add(new Record("Test", "Test", "test@test.com"));
```

Comment: even if i am trying to create an array list of objects from a class I created?

Comment: Nope. Hence `new Record("Test", "Test", "test@test.com")`